# R4.0 performance: dataframes vs lists, loops vs vectorized - example with constant vector substraction

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, vectorization

It is the third time I am reading Hadley Wickham's notorious [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html) and in the second chapter he explains why iterating over lists is better than over dataframes. Everything seems reasonable, familiar, and expected. The example function subtracts a vector of medians from each column of a dataframe, it is basically a form of centering. To test things out I ran the code provided by Grosser, Bumann &  Wickham in [Advanced R Solutions](https://advanced-r-solutions.rbind.io/names-and-values.html).

```r
library(bench)

# Function to generate random dataframe
create_random_df <- function(nrow, ncol) {
  random_matrix <- matrix(runif(nrow * ncol), nrow = nrow)
  as.data.frame(random_matrix)
}

# For loop function that runs on dataframe
subtract_df <- function(x, medians) {
  for (i in seq_along(medians)) {
    x[[i]] <- x[[i]] - medians[[i]]
  }
  x
}

# Same for loop function but that runs on list
subtract_list <- function(x, medians) {
  x <- as.list(x)
  x <- subtract_df(x, medians)
  list2DF(x)
}


benchmark_medians <- function(ncol) {
  df <- create_random_df(nrow = 1e4, ncol = ncol)
  medians <- vapply(df, median, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  
  bench::mark(
    "data frame" = subtract_df(df, medians),
    "list" = subtract_list(df, medians),
    time_unit = "ms"
  )
}

# Results
results <- bench::press(
  ncol = c(1, 10, 50, 100, 250, 300, 400, 500, 750, 1000),
  benchmark_medians(ncol)
)
#> Running with:
#>     ncol
#>  1     1
#>  2    10
#>  3    50
#>  4   100
#>  5   250
#>  6   300
#>  7   400
#>  8   500
#>  9   750
#> 10  1000

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  results,
  aes(ncol, median, col = attr(expression, "description"))
) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_smooth() +
  labs(
    x = "Number of Columns",
    y = "Execution Time (ms)",
    colour = "Data Structure"
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Again, nothing out of the ordinary, the authors explain that:

> When working directly with the data frame, the execution time grows
> quadratically with the number of columns in the input data. This is
> because (e.g.) the first column must be copied n times, the second
> column n-1 times, and so on. When working with a list, the execution
> time increases only linearly.
>
> Obviously in the long run, linear growth creates shorter run-times,
> but there is some cost to this strategy — we have to convert between
> data structures with as.list() and list2DF(). Even though this is fast
> and probably doesn’t hurt much, the improved approach doesn’t really
> pay off in this scenario until we get to a data frame that is about
> 300 columns wide (with the exact value depending on the
> characteristics of the system running the code).

But then, I thought to myself that I work a lot with dataframes, not lists and surely I would be able to write a function that runs in decent time on a dataframe with many columns. How wrong was I! I now have more questions than when I started: aren't for loops supposed to be slower than vectorized operations? did version 4 of R get new optimizations I am not aware of? why is `sweep` function so slow? shouldn't matrix/vectorized operations be at least as fast as the loops? does the garbage collector slow things down significantly? what am I doing wrong inside the functions (I surely am in some of them)?

```r
library(bench)
  
# Function to generate random dataframe
create_random_df <- function(nrow, ncol) {
  random_matrix <- matrix(runif(nrow * ncol), nrow = nrow)
  as.data.frame(random_matrix)
}

# For loop function that runs on dataframe
subtract_df <- function(x, medians) {
  for (i in seq_along(medians)) {
    x[[i]] <- x[[i]] - medians[[i]]
  }
  x
}

# Same for loop function but that runs on list
subtract_list <- function(x, medians) {
  x <- as.list(x)
  x <- subtract_df(x, medians)
  list2DF(x)
}
  
# 5 Functions that I thought should be decently fast 
my_mapply <- function(x, medians) {
  as.data.frame(
    mapply(
      function(x, medians){x - medians},
      x,
      medians
    )  
  )
} 

my_sweep <- function(x, medians) {
  sweep(x, 2, medians)
}

my_apply <- function(x, medians) {
  x <- t(apply(x, 1, function(a) a - medians))
  as.data.frame(x)
}

my_vectorized <-function(x, medians) { 
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  x <- t(t(x) - medians)
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  x
}  

my_vectorized2 <- function(x, medians) {
  ones <- rep(1, nrow(x))
  x_median <- ones %*% t(medians)
  x - x_median
}


benchmark_medians <- function(ncol) {
  df <- create_random_df(nrow = 1e4, ncol = ncol)
  medians <- vapply(df, median, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  
  bench::mark(
    "data frame" = subtract_df(df, medians),
    "list" = subtract_list(df, medians),
    "my_mapply" = my_mapply(df, medians), 
    "my_sweep" = my_sweep(df, medians),
    # "my_apply" = my_apply(df, medians),   # excluded because it is very very slow compared with the others
    "my_vectorized" = my_vectorized(df, medians),
    "my_vectorized2" = my_vectorized2(df, medians),
    time_unit = "ms"
  )
}

# Have a quick check on dataframe with only 3 columns
benchmark_medians(3)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   expression        min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>      <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 data frame     0.0463 0.0884    12769.    4.44MB     55.9
#> 2 list           0.0640 0.0693    12944.  486.86KB    127. 
#> 3 my_mapply      0.152  0.160      5772.    1.05MB    124. 
#> 4 my_sweep       1.14   1.18        809.    2.21MB     38.7
#> 5 my_vectorized  0.208  0.212      4253.     1.1MB     89.2
#> 6 my_vectorized2 0.844  0.875      1074.    1.93MB     46.4

# Results
results <- bench::press(
  ncol = c(1, 10, 50, 100, 250, 300, 400, 500, 750, 1000),
  benchmark_medians(ncol)
)
#> Running with:
#>     ncol
#>  1     1
#>  2    10
#>  3    50
#>  4   100
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#>  5   250
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#>  6   300
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#>  7   400
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#>  8   500
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#>  9   750
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> 10  1000
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  results,
  aes(ncol, median, col = attr(expression, "description"))
) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_smooth() +
  labs(
    x = "Number of Columns",
    y = "Execution Time (ms)",
    colour = "Data Structure"
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

These results are pretty much consistent throughout all of my testing, regardles of the characteristics of generated data.
Any insights are appreciated and any advice on performance or certain function/family of function use is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Aren't for loops supposed to be slower than vectorized operations? / Shouldn't matrix/vectorized operations be at least as fast as the loops?

It depends. However, I think there is a misunderstanding about vectorized operations (and data.frames). Consider `my_vectorized2()`:

```
my_vectorized2 <- function(x, medians) {
  ones <- rep(1, nrow(x))
  x_median <- ones %*% t(medians)
  x - x_median
}
```

The "bottleneck" here is the 4th line. Contrary to what you assume (I presume), `x - medians` dot *not* trigger vectorized computation: `x` is not a matrix but a data.frame (i.e., a list). Arithmetic with data.frames works because convenient methods have been implemented. That this should not be taken for granted can be seen in the example below.

```
# `+` method for data.frames
`as.data.frame(1:5) + as.data.frame(6:10)`.

1   7
2   9
3  11
4  13
5  15

# no `+` method for lists!
`as.list(1:5) + as.list(6:10)`

Error in as.list(1:5) + as.list(6:10) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

However, these convenient data.frames methods are, in short, less efficient than calculations based on vectors. By profiling the code, we can take a closer look where time is spent:

```
df <- create_random_df(nrow = 1e4, ncol = 1000)
profvis::profvis(my_vectorized2(df, medians))
```

[image]

By far the most time is spent by `Ops.data.frame()`, splitting the frame for the `"-"` method, it seems.

> why is the `sweep` function so slow? / does the garbage collector slow things down significantly?

I am not too familiar with the inner workings of `sweep()` but the poor performance is essentially due to the issue discussed above. In addition, multiple references are created, which results in copies. Garbage collection also seems to have a fair share (this is confirmed by profiling). This is similar to your approaches using `mapply()` and `apply()`. `my_vectorized()` is comparably fast because the computation *is* vectorized. However, conversion from and to data.frame and transposition with `t()` is costly (as it results in copies) and thus should be avoided.

In summary, a piece of advice would be to generally use matrices instead of data.frames when you strive for performance in arithmetic operations.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Yea, when writing `my_vectorized2` I figgured that it was actually operating on the dataframe and that I should have transformed it to matrix and then back to dataframe. That would probably have made it faster than `my_vectorized` because `t()` is not applied to the full dataframe. Thanks again.